# $(\lambda z. zy)(\lambda z. zy)$ - reducing using $\beta$ reduction and $\alpha$ conversion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computability, lambda-calculus, formal-systems

Good day . I need to reduce the following expression of lambda calculus:

$(\lambda z. zy)(\lambda z. zy)$

Now, since I am having the variable $y$ in both the left and right pair of parentheses, I think that I should rename one of them to another variable, namely $u$.

$(\lambda z. zu)(\lambda z. zy)$. Now, by reducing I get: $(\lambda z. zy)u$ , which yields $uy$

**However: in the solution of the exercise I found online they did not rename the variable $y$!** I am not sure why. Since the variable $y$ appears *in both* pairs of parentheses we'd need to rename one of them. They simply got $(\lambda z. zy)y$ which evaluates to $yy$.

The reason I'm asking is because in one other example, they did rename one of the variables. It's this example:

$$(\lambda x. \lambda y. xy)(\lambda x. \lambda y. xy)$$

What they did is they renamed one of the variables $y$ to $z$ so they got

$$(\lambda x. \lambda \color{red}z. x \color{red}z)(\lambda x. \lambda y. xy)$$

Can anyone explain why we **don't** rename the variable in the first example, but we need to do it in the second example?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot rename free variables! You can only rename bound variables (so you can rename $\lambda x. xy$ to $\lambda z. zy$ but you cannot rename $\lambda x.xy$ to $\lambda x. xz$ since the result becomes different).

Think of this: $\lambda x.x$ is the identity function, and it is $\alpha$-equivalent to $\lambda y.y$ or to $\lambda z.z$ or any other identity function. So here you can rename. While instead, $x$ is the variable $x$, and if you try renaming it to $y$ you are changing the semantics of the term: $x$ is not $\alpha$-equivalent to $y$.

Hence, in $(\lambda z. zy)(\lambda z. zy)$ you cannot rename $y$, if you really wanted you could rename $z$ and get $(\lambda z. zy)(\lambda u. uy)$ and get $yy$ as you would get without renaming, clearly.

I think in your second example they did rename the variable because the variable $y$ wasn't free in the term $t$ they were substituting for $x$. So if they didn't rename it they would get
$\lambda y. (\lambda x. \lambda y. xy)y$ that is different from the true result that is $\lambda z. (\lambda x. \lambda y. xy)z$ or any equivalent form like $\lambda u. (\lambda x. \lambda y. xy)u$ or $\lambda y. (\lambda x. \lambda z. xz)y$.

Comment: What if I have $(\lambda x. yx)y$. If I don't rename $y$, the result is $yy$. If I rename it to $z$, the result is $zy$. Even if they are not equal, the correct one would be $yy$ since I can't rename unbound variables right?

Comment: *free variables.

Comment: @johndoe yes exactly, the correct one in that case is $yy$